# Gimp opens too big for the screen in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, gimp

Gimp 2.8.2 opens too big for the screen (some of it is visible in the lower workspace when using workspace switcher). If i maximize it, it's too big on top.

How can i make it be within the screen?

---

Thank you for your answer, but i still haven't resolved my issue. I somehow managed to keep it on one screen in workspace switcher (by temporarily hiding all docks), but when i click on it it's still too big.

Answer (score 12):

If we had the same problem, I could be available to reset the Gimp size by

**Edit** >**Preferences** > *window management and clicking* '" reset saved window positions to default value' ".

[Source](http://gimpforums.com/thread-can-only-see-half-the-image-help-anyone)

Answer (score 5):

Ran in to something similar: the window was too tall, and I couldn't resize it vertically. It turned out that the tool pane on the left was fixing the window to a minimum height.

Increasing the width of the pane (hover over the area between the tools and the document, click drag to the right) allowed me to resize the window.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a [known bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=660475), intended to be fixed in version 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried maximising it? It never opens maximised for me - when I maximise it (old style window buttons, top right) it seems to fit ok. I'm in 12.04 for the record.

Answer (score 0):

With the workspace switcher you should be able to grab the window and move it.  Just move that window until it's min/max buttons are click-able.  Then maximize the window.  Then if you want you can grab it and from the top bar and drag it to the side of your screen and the sticky edges should kick in and allow you dock to half the screen size. You can also go to windows in the title bar and dock the extra windows to the main window instead of having the usual three windows.  I think the option is called "Single dock window"

hope this helps